# How to disable JustMyCode for Python in Visual Studio 2019 (not VS Code)

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, breakpoints

In Visual Studio 2019 when I create a python project using the "from existing code" template, I can't get breakpoints to actually work. When I start debugging, the breakpoint turns black and says the following when I hover over it:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Breakpoint in file excluded by filters. Note: may be excluded because of "justMyCode" option (default == true). Try setting "justMyCode": false in the debug configuration (e.g launch.json)

However, all of the info online about `launch.json` relates to VS Code not VS 2019.

If I try mimicking what you're meant to do for VS Code but in VS 2019 and put the `launch.json` file in my project's `.vs` folder then it doesn't do anything. I confirmed I have the json file configured correctly by using it with VS Code and it does indeed fix the breakpoint problem there.

Disabling the "Just My Code" option in the Tools -> Options window in VS 2019 doesn't do anything either. So how are you meant to do this in VS 2019?

Comment: AFAIK launch setting file for Visual Studio (NOT Code) is launch.vs.json under .vs folder (so NOT launch.json). I can debug Python under VS2022 and start py scripts with arguments but the "justMyCode":false setting seems to be ignored.
And I agree, it's frustrating to see how most information goes to VS Code.

Answer (score 6):

In Tools / Options go to Python/Debugging and check:
Enable debugging of the Python standard library.

This works in Visual Studio 2022.